# the set of continuous complex-valued functions on an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ is not normable

Tags: functional-analysis

why the set of continuous complex-valued functions on an open set of $R^n$ is not normable?

Comment: With what topology?

Comment: Well, I think that we can safely guess that he means the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @AlexM. Unlikely, the usual topology considered is the topology of locally uniform convergence.

Comment: The question by @G.Sassatelli is crucial, which topology? Similar to the reasoning [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918318/there-is-no-norm-in-c-infty-a-b-which-makes-it-a-banach-space), we can endow the space with norms making it a Banach space, but for a non-empty open set, these norms don't play well with the usual notions of convergence.