# Is there another (non-equivalent) norm on $C[0,1]$ that makes it a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $E=C([0,1])$ as a vector space. Is there a norm $N$ on $E$ such that

- $(E,N)$ is Banach,
- $N$ is not equivalent to the usual norm $N_\infty$?

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918318/there-is-no-norm-in-c-infty-a-b-which-makes-it-a-banach-space) for something similar. But I'd be very very surprised if someone could _explicitly_ construct such a norm.

Comment: @DanielFischer: In a sense it *can't* be done explicitly, in that it is consistent with ZF+DC that no other such norm exists.  It's consistent with ZF+DC that all linear maps between Banach spaces are continuous, and if the identity map from $(E, N_\infty)$ to $(E,N)$ is continuous then by the open mapping theorem it's a homeomorphism, meaning $N, N_\infty$ are equivalent.